# Initializing PHP classes in the Web server/browser context

Tags: php

I am writing a script that talks to a database, and transforms the content and puts it into an XML file.

I am trying to utilize best practices, and as part of library re-use, I have found the following classes to be beneficial:

#### Symfony components:

- Yaml : for parsing and loading database info.,
- DI Container : for injecting dependencies

#### Others:

- PHPExcel, the *amazing* excel library
- Doctrine DBAL to get an easy PDO wrapper
- Mockery for obtaining easy mocks during testing

My core business class, `ExcelExporter`, will need all these files functioning harmoniously with each other. I also need a place where I can initialize by own class, and inject these dependencies in.

I am confused as to where to do this. If I were building a web page, I'd say I'd put the initialization & configuration process inside index.php and finally call ExcelExporter to do its thing when a user loads index.php in the browser. Is there a better way for this bootstrapping process? What's the most common approach?

Comment: Code please. What have you tried?

Comment: If you are not using any framework you can create a bootstrap file and load them there.

Comment: I'm pretty overwhelmed at the thought of all this, I would like a little nudge in the right direction at the moment to get started with code.

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im So do you suggest I just make a bootstrap.php file and call that from index.php when necessary?

Comment: Call bootstrap.php only once. But it should load all your necessary class to start the application. To load more class upon need use autoloader.

Comment: Ah yes, that sounds great... can you put that in an answer please?

Comment: Use Symfony's bootstrap examples.

Comment: Hello StackOverflow, I have added more details to the question. I also have an answer now that I have solved this problem. Kindly reopen the question so I can try to contribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are not using any framework. Only using symphony components. If you were using a framework it would have been done by the framework. But for vanila framework you need

1. A single entry point for the application (say `index.php`)
2. A `bootstrap.php` file that loads initial classes and external resources. Many framework uses this bootstrap files. Just look at the file structure you'll find them. The name might not be `bootstrap.php`.
3. Once your application is loaded use a autoloader to load on-demand classes. This [autoloader](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) should be initialized on bootstrap.

   ```
   function my_autoloader($class) {
       include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
   }
   spl_autoload_register('my_autoloader');
   ```

Answer (score 3):

You should totaly use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md) for this task.

It will handle **vendors and autoloading** for you.

Here is a quick setup:

```
curl -s https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar init
php composer.phar require symfony/dom-crawler:dev-master doctrine/dbal:2.4.x-dev
php composer.phar install
```

You will have a `vendor` directory with your dependencies. Then the bootstrap file is simply initializing what you have to do. Autoloading is handled by Composer:

```
// Then add this on top of your bootstrap file
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Comment: Excellent! Didn't think of *this* approach! I can't vote up at the moment (can do in 57 mins), I hope you don't mind if I don't accept yet? This solution is great also, but it's tough to choose between this or the other one...

Answer (score 1):

Based on Damien's answer, I found that Composer offers the easiest method to do this.

Now, my `ExportExcel` class lives in the `src/` directory. The structure of my directory is:

```
src/
vendor/
index.php
bootstrap.php
composer.json
```

Within `composer.json`, I also asked it to load my classes for me:

```
{
    "name": "adityamenon/excel_export",
    "description": "Export data into a custom excel sheet format",
    "require": {
        "symfony/dependency-injection": "2.2.x-dev",
        "symfony/yaml": "2.1.x-dev",
        "doctrine/dbal": "2.4.x-dev",
        "mockery/mockery": "dev-master",
        "CodePlex/PHPExcel": "1.7.8"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {"ExportExcel": "src/"}
    },
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "aditya menon",
            "email": "adityamenon90@gmail.com"
        }
    ]
}
```

I just need to run `$ composer install`  for all the dependencies to appear magically within `vendor/`.

PSR-0 is easy to follow. I just made a file called `ExportExcel.php` with a namespaced class inside called `ExportExcel`:

```
namespace ExportExcel;

class ExportExcel {

    public function __construct(\ExportExcel\DbConvenience $db_convenience)
    {
        $this->DbConvenience = $db_convenience;
    }

    public function writeExcelFile()
    {
        // ...do stuff here
    }

}
```

Finally, here's bootstrap.php, which takes care of autoloading stuff I need as well as injecting dependencies:

```
<?php

// composer autoloads dependencies
// also configured to load from src/
$loader = require('vendor/autoload.php');

// load configuration (only db right now)
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
$yaml_config = Yaml::parse('config.yml');

// load the database
$db_config = new Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
$conn = Doctrine\DBAL\DriverManager::getConnection($yaml_config, $db_config);

// load the convenience classes
$DbConvenience = new ExportExcel\DbConvenience($conn);

// use the dependency injector to load the exporter with DB
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
$sc = new ContainerBuilder();

$sc->setParameter('dbconvenience.class', 'ExportExcel\DbConvenience');
$sc->setParameter('exportexcel.class', 'ExportExcel\ExportExcel');

$sc
    ->register('dbconvenience', '%dbconvenience.class%')
    ->addArgument($conn);

$sc
    ->register('exportexcel', '%exportexcel.class%')
    ->addArgument(new Reference('dbconvenience'));

// here's the most important class of 'em all
$ExportExcel = $sc->get('exportexcel');
```

**Finally** in index.php, the first line is `require('bootstrap.php');`, and off I go. I can make calls to functions inside ExportExcel with $ExportExcel->doStuff();

Please feel free to add comments and shorten/improve this answer. Solving this puzzle was a bit hard and took a bit of reading around but everything is so clear in hindsight.